# Warning en comparaciones con Null en Dart y Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Desde la última vez que utilicé Flutter en 2020 hasta ahora han cambiado muchas cosas. Especialmente todo lo referente a los valores null y el famoso null-safety, que nos trae muchos dolores de cabeza.

Lo que planteo es una duda teórica que no logro entender.
Tomando como ejemplo este fragmento de código:

```
widget.argForm == null ? "Add new form" : "Edit form",
```

Se trata de un condicional donde quiero que se escriba una cosa u otra dependiendo de si el objeto es o no null.
Aquí me aparece un warning que dice lo siguiente:

```
The operand can't be null, so the condition is always false. (Documentation)  Try removing the condition, an enclosing condition, or the whole conditional statement.
```

Sin embargo, en la práctica, esta condición funciona correctamente, y no sucede eso de que la condición vaya a ser siempre falsa.

Quisiera saber como es esto posible o si existe alguna forma más correcta de hacer este tipo de comparaciones en Dart. También si se trata de algo que pueda dar problemas en el futuro, o que tan solo es un simple warning al que no prestar atención.

Comment: Como estás declarando la variable argForm en la clase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo de null-safety al principio es un poco pesado de entender, pero luego se hace sencillo, te dejo este tutorial para que lo entiendas mejor: https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety

Sobre tu error, seguramente en tu widget, has definido la variable como non-nulabe.

```dart
class TuWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const TuWidget(this.argForm);
  
// Esta variable no puede ser nula
  final String argForm;
```

Por lo que al hacer la validación el analyzer te dice que esa variable nunca será nula, por lo que la condición siempre será falsa:

```dart
widget.argForm == null ? "Add new form" : "Edit form",
```

Si hubieras definido tu variable como nullable, así:

```dart
class TuWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const TuWidget({this.argForm});
  
// Esta variable puede ser nula
  final String? argForm;
```

Entonces ya no tendrías el warning.